# Labels in training dataset

Tags: dataset, label, roboflow

I need some help here. I found dome training dataset of cyclists and was looking for any labels in it, but couldn't find any. Does anyone know how to possibly add them or if I'm just blind? Thanks

The dataset in question: [Dataset](https://universe.roboflow.com/pawel-brzozowski/cyclists_database)

I tried looking elsewhere on internet, but I'm new into this and don't know exactly what to look for.

Comment: What do you mean by labels?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that as a new learner of this field and first time user of Roboflow, the concept of labels is unfamiliar.

In a dataset of training images, a *label* is some form of demarcation, or- well- labelling, on the image to identify something of interest in that image. In other words, the label is the thing which marks out what you want your model to recognize in an image when it is being trained with that dataset.

Roboflow is really useful for labelling images, as it provides some powerful tools to mark up images with things you want to see. In your dataset of cyclists, the labels are the boxes drawn around cyclists in images.

[Example Label from Cyclist Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUn25.jpg)

You wouldn't need to add labels to this dataset, as it has already been labelled to identify some classes (the different types of objects being labelled). You can see the classes provided on the right hand column of the Overview screen, or alternately in the Images tab by clicking on the Classes dropdown. In your case, your dataset has images with labels to identify people and the presence and orientation of cyclists.

If you feel the need to label these images yourself to modify the dataset or classes to your own needs (you'd do this if the images don't seem marked up the way you want them to be, or if you want to add some of your own data to this dataset for usage), you'd have to start your own copy for personal use. Here's how you could do that:

1. Check the project type and classes in the right hand column.
2. Click on the Projects button on the navigation bar at the top of the screen.
3. Click on Create New Project. Set the project type and classes as they were in the original project (unless these are things you wish to change in your version).
4. Head over to the public dataset you wish to clone, and click on the Images tab.
5. Select all the images you wish to clone, then click the Clone Selected Images button at the top right hand area.
6. Select your workspace and the project you just created.
7. Choose one of the options in the Edit Annotations section. Select Import Images and Annotations if you want to use the labels provided already, or select Import Raw Images if you just want to copy the blank images and add labels to them yourself.
8. Head over to your dataset, and you'll be able to mark up the copied images and add your own ones as needed. Hope this helped, and happy labelling!